# How to format arrays in a different method?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I format my array as this? I've tried many different methods but I can't seem to get it to work.

I want it to return something like this 
"Avg of 1 2 3 4 5 is 3.00"

```
public class AverageNumber {

private static int[] n = new int[5];
private static double total = 0;

public static void main(String[] a) { 
    AverageNumber object = new AverageNumber();
    object.Dialogue();
}

private void Dialogue() { 
    int count = 1;

    System.out.println("Skriv inn 5 tall" + count++);
    for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++){
        n[i] = Konsoll.readInt("Tall");
        total = total + n[i];
    }

    double avg = total / n.length;

    System.out.println("Avg of " + formatArray() + "  is " + avg); 
}

private static double formatArray() {
    //Return all numbers
}
```

}

Comment: Does it have to be an Object or any program implementation is ok?

Comment: instead of calling `formatArray()` and doing work there, try: `Arrays.toString(n)`

Comment: @JoshW. Any program implementation is fine. Doesn't have to be an object...

Comment: @kaan The whole point is to do it manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formatArray` method should return `String`, like this :

```
private static String formatArray() {
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n.length ; i++)
        s+= String.valueOf(n[i])+" ";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for.

Comment: It would be better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of repeatedly creating new `String` objects (by using `+=`). The initial capacity can be specified in the constructor, like this: `new StringBuilder(n.length)`, which would guard against potentially resizing/growing the StringBuilder if `n` doesn't fit in the default 16 character length (or any subsequent growths).

Comment: @kaan yeah, i know, i didn't want to make it complicated, the time complexity of appending in `StringBuilder` is `O(1)`. and it's much more better than using `+=` for appending, thank you.